# pdfnet document text annotation doesn't save if keyboard is active

Tags: ios, pdfnet

Just updated PDFNet.framework to 6.2.1
When I edit a doc with text fields in the PDFViewCtrl and then save it with

```
    NSData *pdfData = [pdfViewCtrl.GetDoc SaveToBuf:e_linearized];
```

all field values get saved except the one that has focus.

Recently (on v6.1.0 or smth) I used to do the following

```
    [pdfViewCtrl setTool:nil];
```

now there's the toolManager instead of tool property, but it throws exception "pdfViewCtrl Is Nil" when I try to

```
    [toolManager setTool:nil];
```

How do I fix it so that all fields including focused one are saved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
[toolManager changeTool:[PanTool class]];
```

or

```
[toolManager setTool:[[PanTool alloc] initWithPDFViewCtrl:myPDFViewCtrl]];
```